# How to display texture in opengl es 1.1

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1

I'm just learning open-angle and I need to render a texture on my existing object in the scene.
I get the texture id and then I want to output it to my object. Here is my object code

```
        val sqrSize = 20
        val vtx = FloatArray(1530)
        var vtxCtr = 0
        //we use the offset to produce the checkered pattern
        var x = -130
        var offset = 0
        while (x < 130) {
            var y = -130 + offset
            while (y < 130) {
                //each square is 2 triangles = 6 vertices = 18 floats [x/y/z]
                vtx[vtxCtr + 0] = x.toFloat()
                vtx[vtxCtr + 1] = -20f //floor is 2 points below 0
                vtx[vtxCtr + 2] = y.toFloat()
                vtx[vtxCtr + 3] = (x + sqrSize).toFloat()
                vtx[vtxCtr + 4] = -20f
                vtx[vtxCtr + 5] = y.toFloat()
                vtx[vtxCtr + 6] = x.toFloat()
                vtx[vtxCtr + 7] = -20f
                vtx[vtxCtr + 8] = (y + sqrSize).toFloat()
                vtx[vtxCtr + 9] = (x + sqrSize).toFloat()
                vtx[vtxCtr + 10] = -20f
                vtx[vtxCtr + 11] = y.toFloat()
                vtx[vtxCtr + 12] = x.toFloat()
                vtx[vtxCtr + 13] = -20f
                vtx[vtxCtr + 14] = (y + sqrSize).toFloat()
                vtx[vtxCtr + 15] = (x + sqrSize).toFloat()
                vtx[vtxCtr + 16] = -20f
                vtx[vtxCtr + 17] = (y + sqrSize).toFloat()
                vtxCtr += 18
                y += sqrSize * 2
            }
            x += sqrSize
            offset = sqrSize - offset
        }
        StoreVertexData(gl, vtx, mFLOOR)
```

Next, I save the object in the buffer and then draw it. Render code below

```
    private fun DrawObject(gl: GL11, pShapeType: Int, pObjNum: Int) {
        //activate vertex array type
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        //get vertices for this object id
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pObjNum)
        //each vertex is made up of 3 floats [x\y\z]
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)
        //draw triangles
        gl.glDrawArrays(pShapeType, 0, mBufferLen[pObjNum])
        //unbind from memory
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
    }
```

And then I draw the shape in OnDrawFrame, but before that I apply the texture.

```
            gl.glColor4f(0.2f, 1f, 1f, 1f)
            gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D)
            gl.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureHandle)
            gl.glTexCoordPointer(2,GL11.GL_FLOAT,0,bufferTexture)
            DrawObject(gl, GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, mFLOOR)
```

The texture does not appear at startup, what could be the problem? And what is the best way to display a texture on an object in OpenGl ES 1.1

I thought that the problem might be that I incorrectly specified the texture coordinates (they are below), but apparently, these coordinates indicate that the texture should cover the entire object
    `private var textureCoord = floatArrayOf( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, )`